# ASP.NET razor pages menu

Tags: c#, menu

I am working on a project in ASP.NET Core with Razor pages and I have a menu that has a picture and a link. I am trying to make all the area of the `li` clickable as a link.

Here is the code for my menu in the view markup:

```
<div id="myMenu">
    <ul>
        <li>
             <img src=""/>
             <a asp-page="/Index"><h5>Index</h5></a>
        </li>

        <li>
             <img src=""/>
             <a asp-page="/Index2"><h5>Index2</h5></a>
        </li>

         <li>
             <img src=""/>
             <a asp-page="/Index3"><h5>Index3</h5></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my CSS, I tried:

```
#myMenu ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
}

li {
    height: 90px;  
}
```

The problem is that I can only click on the link, not on the full area of the `li`. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you can put all the content you want to be clickable inside the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="#"/>
    <h5>Title</h5>
</a>
```

Heres an example:

https://codepen.io/fernandesdiegod/pen/VweNXPB

Comment: The problem is that the image in my menu does not occupy all the area of the li. I have a small image and near it I have the link.

Comment: Apparently your code works also for the image that is not the size of the li.